# Angular 16 How to get Data from a popup modal using NgbModal

Tags: html, angular

Hello I have a application that has a search box, when user types in a name for a product if found a popup modal appears with image of item found, if not it shows sorry not found. What I am struggling to do when the user clicks to add to favorites from popup it should go into a url/db.

I am able to initial the data and it goes into database fine, which means my service is working the way intended. What I have been trying to do is get the data from the instance of the opened modal, right now when ever I click to add to favorites(which calls a function who makes a call to service which adds to database)  it does not get what is currently in the modal it continues to give me the initialize data. I know I need a instance of the modal everything I have tried from my research such as modelRef and componentInstance in which I get error.  Can someone please point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong.  I have been trying to figure this out for a while. A snippet of my code is included.

//There is a lot going on in the Header Component will only include relevant code.

```
//HeaderComponent.ts

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit  {

  @ViewChild('Qpaper') public qpaper: any;
  @Input() public data:any;

  sizeBy!: string;     /*The definite assignment assertion */
  submitted=false;
  Valuesize!: string;

  constructor( private msg: MessengerService, private cartService:CartService,private 
  accountService: AccountService, private modalService: NgbModal, private config: 
  NgbModalConfig, private productService: ProductService, private 
  searchService:SearchService, private auth:AuthService,  public 
  activeModal:NgbActiveModal, public prodcomp:ProductItemComponent,
  private _imageService:ImageService, private formBuilder: UntypedFormBuilder,private 
  alertService: AlertService, private wishlistService:WishlistService, private 
 _wishlistitemService: WishlistItemService)

  {

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  sizeBy: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  this.loadCartItems();
  this.initializeData();   

 }

 initializeData(){

 this.data = {
 id: 0o1,
 name: "Shear Top",
 size: "",
 description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
 industry.",
 imageUrl: "http://localhost:4200/assets/sexy.png",
 price: 299

}

/*this.data=this.activeModal; this will make data empty in db*/
}

  searchImage(name:string){

  console.log(name);
  let query = name;

  this._imageService.getImage(query.trim()).subscribe( result =>{
  this.hasQuery = true;
  console.log("Image Results", result);
  this.products = result;

  this.openDialog();
}) 

}

openDialog(){

 const modalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
 backdrop: false
};

 this. modalRef= this.modalService.open(this.qpaper, modalOptions);

 // Get the instance of ActiveModal
//this.data = this.activeModal; 

 }

 handleAddToWishlistitem(){  //This function is called when user clicks on favorites

 //Get the data that was was passed to the model when it was opened

//alert(this.modalRef.data);



 //This does get data from popoup only as object object is what is returned
 const data = this._wishlistitemService.getDataFromPopup();
 alert( data); //as object object just a test

  this._wishlistitemService.saveData(this.data).subscribe(() => {

   alert(this.data) //object object
  });

   this.addedToWishlist =true;

   }


 }



 //wishlist-item.service.ts

   saveData(product:Product):Observable<any>{

   alert(product);  //object object which is good

   return this.http.post(wishlistitemUrl,  {product});

}


 getDataFromPopup() {
   // Get the data from the popup.
      alert("Inside get data")
     return this.http.get('/data');  //This gives me object object just a test 

   

 }


  //headerComponent.html
       <div *ngFor = "let itemProduct of products">
               <img [src]="itemProduct.imageUrl" alt="Popup Clothing">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="float-left">{{itemProduct.name}}</p>
                <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="float-left form-check">Size:
                  <label class="form-check-label checkbox-inline" for="small">  
                  <input  type="radio"  name="sizeBy" formControlName="sizeBy" 
                  id="small" [ngClass]=f.sizeBy value="S" required >
                  S</label>                               
                  <label class="form-check-label checkbox-inline" for="medium">
                  <input type="radio" name="sizeBy" formControlName="sizeBy" id="medium"   
                  [ngClass]=f.sizeBy value="M" required >
                  M</label>  
                  <label class="form-check-label checkbox-inline" for="large">
                  <input  type="radio" name="sizeBy" formControlName="sizeBy" id="large" 
                  [ngClass]=f.sizeBy value="L"  required>
                  L</label>                      
                  <div *ngIf="f.sizeBy.errors?.required"><b>You Must Choose A Size</b> 
                  </div>   
                  <p class="card-text" style="text-align:left; width: 150px"> 
                  {{itemProduct.description | slice: 0:20}}...</p>
                  <p  style="text-align:left; width:100px;">
                  <strong>{{ itemProduct.price | currency }}</strong>
                   <i *ngIf ="addedToWishlist" class="fas fa-heart float-right"  
                   (click)="handleRemoveItemFromWishListitem()"></i>
                   <i *ngIf ="!addedToWishlist" class="far fa-heart float-right" 
                   (click)="handleAddToWishlistitem();"></i>
                  </p>                    
                <div class="-flex justify-content-between align-items-left">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="submit"  onclick="handleAddToCart()">
                      <img  src="assets/shopping_cart_outline001.png">
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>    
                
              </div>
             </div>
```